PDFBox how to insert a page from a donor document and then close the donor
I have a document processing pipeline in which I need to add pages to from a donor document.  All examples I have found to clone the donor page do not continue to work after the donor document has been closed. I need to open a donor, pull a page from it, insert it into the document in the pipeline, and then close the donor (or it closes itself when it goes out of scope). I am using PDFBox 2.0.27
My bestapproximation of the solution from StackOverflow 20084117
URL donorUrl = this.class.classLoader.getResource("files/DonorDocument.pdf")
File donorFile = new File(donorUrl.toURI());
PDDocument donorDocument = PDDocument.load(donorFile);
PDPage donorPage = donorDocument.getPage(0);

// trying to clone the page per SO 20084117
COSDictionary donorDictionary = donorPage.getCOSObject(); // they said getCOSDictionary but that is 404
COSDictionary newPageDictionary = new COSDictionary(donorDictionary);
newPageDictionary.removeItem(COSName.ANNOTS);
PDPage newPage = new PDPage(newPageDictionary);

targetDocument.addPage(newPage);

donorDocument.close();

// the following line will return a page which has been closed
targetDocument.getPage(document.numberOfPages - 1);

I aslso tried a number of variations using PDFCloneUtility
PDFCloneUtility cloner = new PDFCloneUtility(donorDocument);
COSBase clonedDOcument = cloner.cloneForNewDocument(donorPage.getCOSObject());
COSDictionary clonedDictionary = clonedDOcument as COSDictionary;
COSDictionary newPageDict = new COSDictionary(clonedDictionary);
PDPage newPage = new PDPage(newPageDict);
targetDocument.addPage(clonePage);

donorDocument.close();

// the following line will return a page which has been closed
targetDocument.getPage(document.numberOfPages - 1);

and
PDFCloneUtility cloner = new PDFCloneUtility(donorDocument);
PDPage clonePage = new PDPage();
cloner.cloneMerge(donorPage, clonePage);
targetDocument.addPage(clonePage);

donorDocument.close();

// the following line will return a page which has been closed
targetDocument.getPage(document.numberOfPages - 1);

edit: this method is one stop in an application pipeline. A donor is selected, opened, added, and then the method exits. If I don't close the donor document in this method then it closes itself when it goes out of scope.

Don't close early. Close after you're done. And use 2.0.32.

If the donor document is too large to keep open for long but the target document must remain open for long, consider to copy the pages of interest into an intermediary document which you can store (into memory or into a file) and close early and re-open when needed.

this method is one stop in an application pipeline. A donor is selected, opened, added, and then the method exits. If I don't close the donor document in this method then it closes itself when it goes out of scope

If you can hold the target PDDocument open in memory for a longer time, then you also can keep a list of other ones that shall only be closed after the target document; by keeping them in the list, they won't go out of scope and close prematurely. (Of course you can close and re-open the target document every now and then and close the documents on the list, e.g. whenever the list exceeds a certain size.)

I "fixed" it by passing a list of PDDocument down down down into the method, adding the donor pages to this list, and up at the top of the pipeline when I was done with the target PDF I closed all the donors.
